# How to get final price of a product by rest API?

Tags: magento2, product, price, special-price

I mean the final price that Magento calculated and inserted in **`catalog_product_index_price`** table.

It may have applied special **price/catalog price rule/tier price**, which price is displayed to customer as final price.

Anyone have ideas which API I can use?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: No. I have to call all price API e.g. special price/ tier price, and pick the lowest price by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check using create custom script and add below code :

```
// get token
$userData = array("username" => "addyourusername", "password" => "yourpassword");
$ch = curl_init("https://demo.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = str_replace('"', '', $token);

// get product special price
$ch = curl_init("https://demo.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/SKU-NAME");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($result,true);
$specialPrice = $data['price'];

foreach ($data['custom_attributes'] as $attr) {
    if ($attr['attribute_code'] == 'special_price') {
        $specialPrice = $attr['value'];
    }
}
echo $specialPrice;
```